# SQL query with variable "Where"

Tags: sql

I am new with SQL.

How can I write a query, where the Where condition be dependent on a statement which it will be given from a user?

I have this:

```
SELECT TablePersdaten.Vorname, TablePersdaten.Nachname, TableBezahlung.Datum, TableBezahlung.BelegNr, TableBezahlung.Betrag, Sum(TableBezahlung.Betrag) AS SummevonBetrag
FROM ((TableTeilnehmer INNER JOIN TablePersdaten ON TableTeilnehmer.IDPersdaten = TablePersdaten.IDPersdaten) INNER JOIN TableKurse ON TableTeilnehmer.IDKurs = TableKurse.IDKurs) INNER JOIN TableBezahlung ON TableTeilnehmer.IDTeilnehmer = TableBezahlung.IDStudent
WHERE TableBezahlung.Datum = "VALUE GIVEN FROM USER"
GROUP BY TablePersdaten.Vorname, TablePersdaten.Nachname, TableBezahlung.Datum, TableBezahlung.BelegNr, TableBezahlung.Betrag
ORDER BY TableBezahlung.Datum;
```

EDIT: I'm using Access 2013, but I'm coding everything myself with SQL-Code. The values should be given through a form.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? and what tool is used to receive the user's input?

Comment: This looks like it should be set up as a stored procedure with the value passed in as a parameter.......

Comment: You'll want to use a variable that is assigned a value by the user. As @Mureinik mentioned, you'll need to figure out how to get user input.

Comment: I'm using Access 2013 and the values should be given through a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research stored procedures. You can include user input as a parameter and then pass it to a `WHERE` clause through a declared parameter.

So ideally it would go something like (and beware of the `INT` part it may have to have a different value that corresponds to `table.datum`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc1
  @parameter1 INT

AS
BEGIN
SELECT TablePersdaten.Vorname, TablePersdaten.Nachname, TableBezahlung.Datum, TableBezahlung.BelegNr, TableBezahlung.Betrag, Sum(TableBezahlung.Betrag) AS SummevonBetrag
FROM ((TableTeilnehmer INNER JOIN TablePersdaten ON TableTeilnehmer.IDPersdaten = TablePersdaten.IDPersdaten) INNER JOIN TableKurse ON TableTeilnehmer.IDKurs = TableKurse.IDKurs) INNER JOIN TableBezahlung ON TableTeilnehmer.IDTeilnehmer = TableBezahlung.IDStudent
WHERE TableBezahlung.Datum = @parameter1
GROUP BY TablePersdaten.Vorname, TablePersdaten.Nachname, TableBezahlung.Datum, TableBezahlung.BelegNr, TableBezahlung.Betrag
ORDER BY TableBezahlung.Datum;
END
```

And of course execute the procedure after creation:

```
EXEC dbo.Proc1 '@parameter1value'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you parameterize the input "VALUE GIVEN FROM USER" that might be what you're after.

```
...
WHERE TableBezahlung.Datum = &UserValue
...
```

The single '&' will substitute that value once.  If you use '&&', it will substitute that value through the end of your session.